# Proving that $a_1 \frac{1}{x + c_1} + a_2 \frac{1}{x + c_2} + ... + a_n \frac{1}{x + c_n} \equiv 0$

Tags: real-analysis, functions

Let's consider function:

$$g:[a, b] \ni x \rightarrow g(x) \in \mathbb R$$

given as:

$$g(x) := a_1 \frac{1}{x + c_1} + a_2 \frac{1}{x + c_2} + ... + a_n \frac{1}{x + c_n}$$

where sequence $(c_n): c_{n + 1} > c_n$ and $a_1, a_2,...,a_n \in \mathbb R$ and $a + c_1 > 0$

Moroever let's assume that we have $n$ points $z_1, z_2,..., z_n \in [a, b],\; z_i \neq z_j, \; i \neq j$ such that $g(z_i) = 0$ for $i = 1,2,...,n$.

I want to prove that function $g$ has to be a zero function.

**My work so far**

Let's observe that from our assumptions we have that:

$$\forall_n: a + c_n \ge a + c_1 > 0$$

and

$$\forall_n: x + c_n > a + c_n > 0$$

So our function $g$ is a sum of positive numbers weighted by numbers $a_1, a_2, ..., a_n$. Moreover we know that:

$$\frac{1}{x + c_1} < \frac{1}{x + c_2} < ... < \frac{1}{x + c_n}$$

And here I didn't know how out of fact that $g(z_1) = g(z_2) = ... = g(z_n) = 0$ we'll have that $g \equiv 0$. Could you please give me a hand in proving this statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Consider $f(x) = g(x) \times \prod (x+c_i)$.

Show that

> 1. $f(x)$ is a polynomial

> 2. $f(x)$ has degree at most $n-1$.

> 3. $f(x)$ has at least $n$ zeros.

> 4. Hence $f(x) = 0 $.

> 5. Hence $g(x) = 0 $.

Comment: Am I correct that we don't even need assumptions that $c_{n + 1} > c_n$ and that $a  + c_1 > 0$?

Comment: 1) We want $ c_i \neq c_j$ so as to ensure at least $n$ distinct zeros. 2)  We want  $ a + c_i \neq 0$ so as to avoid division/multiplication by 0, and to ensure that $g:[a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is well defined.  $\quad$ The assumptions you mentioned help ensure these requirements are satisfied. Yes, we could have a slightly broader assumption. (EG We could take $c_i \neq c_j$, $z_i \neq c_j$ and tweak the definition of $g(x): \mathbb{R} - \{z_i \} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, depending on how nitpicky you are with function definitions.)